# Mapping roles in AzureAD to Django groups

Tags: django, django-microsoft-authentication

Okay, I can now do SSO in Django via AzureAD by using [django-microsoft-auth](https://django-microsoft-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#quickstart).
But I would like to manage the groups there as well. For that we configured to pass roles in the token. But how do I map those to Django groups? I don't seem to find any example for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. For anyone with the same question, you'll have to use the 'MICROSOFT_AUTH_AUTHENTICATE_HOOK' setting.

I made a module in my 'app' called aad.py:

```
import jwt
def add_to_group(user, token):
    from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
    id_token = token['id_token']
    token_data = jwt.decode(id_token, options={"verify_signature": False})
    roles = token_data.get('roles', [])
    user.groups.clear()
    for r in roles:
        current_group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name=r)
        current_group.user_set.add(user)
```

in the settings I added the following setting:

```
MICROSOFT_AUTH_AUTHENTICATE_HOOK = "myApp.aad.add_to_group"
```

Of course things could be neater, but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the MICROSOFT_AUTH_AUTHENTICATE_HOOK setting also. I didn't want to erase and re-add users to groups every time they logged in. This code will match the Azure Roles to Django Groups and update them accordingly on login.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
import jwt

def post_microsoft_auth(user, id_token, **kwargs):
    # This extracts the real id_token from the full token that was passed from Azure.
    correct_token = id_token.get('id_token')

    # Decode the token into usable json data
    token_data = jwt.decode(correct_token, options={"verify_signature": False})

    # Gets the list of Azure Roles the user is assigned to
    azure_roles = token_data.get('roles', [])

    # Get the list of Django Groups the current user belongs to. Sort the list.
    django_groups = sorted(list(user.groups.values_list('name', flat = True)))

    # If Azure Roles match Django Groups, do nothing. Else, call update_django_groups()
    if not azure_roles == django_groups:
        update_django_groups(user, azure_roles, django_groups)


def update_django_groups(user, azure_roles, django_groups):
    #Add user to Django Group for each Role assigned in Azure
    for role_name in azure_roles:
        if not user.groups.filter(name=role_name).exists():
            current_group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name=role_name)
            current_group.user_set.add(user)

    #Remove user from Django Group if the Role is no longer assigned in Azure
    for group in django_groups:
        if group not in azure_roles:
            current_django_group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name=group)
            current_django_group.user_set.remove(user)
```